# Matrix being divided by a value unexpectedly

Tags: matlab

Just working on multiply 2 rows of a matrix and making the answer another row within the same matrix. However when putting the new row in the matrix all of the values are for some reason divided by `1.0e+03`.

```
X = (M(1,1:5) .* M(2,1:5));

M(3,1:5) = X(1,1:5)

disp(X)
```

Actual Result

```
X =

   1.0e+03 *

    0.4000    0.5500    0.7000    0.5000    0.6000
    0.0030    0.0005    0.0008    0.0015    0.0050
    1.2000    0.2750    0.5250    0.7500    3.0000
```

Expected Result

```
    400.0000  550.0000  700.0000  500.0000  600.0000
    3.0000    0.5000    0.7500    1.5000    5.0000
    1200      275       525       750       3000
```

Comment: The `X =1.0e+03 *` prefix apply to **all the values in the matrix**. so `0.4*1e3=400` check! `0.5500*1e3=550` check  ... and so on. Your values are fine, you are just surprised by the way they are displayed.

Comment: @Hoki Yeh I noticed that, I'm just wondering if there is a way to get rid of the prefix and display the actual value.

Comment: Enter `format short g` in the command window and then run the code.

Comment: You could try also `disp(cell2mat(compose('%.5f', X)))`.